# Kurento-Group-Call Example for WebRTC

Tags: android, webrtc, kurento

I am working on Kurento API, I have successfully configure Kurento one-2-one in android but I couldn't find any working example for [Kurento-Group-Call](https://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/java/tutorial-groupcall.html) in android.

Can anyone point to any working example? I have tried [OpenVidu](https://github.com/OpenVidu/openvidu-android-app) But it doesn't work with Kurento group Call example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a group call application, I'd still recommend you check out OpenVidu because it builds upon Kurento precisely for the objective of creating videoconference rooms.

Right now there is a Tutorial for Android (and iOS) using Ionic: https://openvidu.io/docs/tutorials/openvidu-ionic/